# Taking the absolute value in inequalities.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

If I've a expression: $-4<3$ and take the absolute value $|-4|<|3|\implies 4<3$ which is false. So I though that maybe the inequality sign would change. But $|-2|<|3| \implies 2>3$ which is also false.

My problem is that I have the inequality $-x<y$ where $x,y>0$. What will happen if I take the absolute value of it: $|-x|<|y|.$ I though it would be $0<|x|<|y|\implies 0<x<y$.

But from the examples above it seems that this ain't true.

EDIT:

I have a increasing sequence $(x_1>x_2>x_3...$ etc.), $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ where all $x's$ are positive and a constant $m=1/2$. The inequality: $-x_n<1/2$ is always valid because the $x's$ are positive. But $x_3=1$. So for all $n \geq 3$, $|-x_n|>1/2$ .

Given this context helps in solving my problem in taking the absolute value?

Taking the absolute value on both side we have for all $n>3, |-x_n|>|1/2|>0 \implies x_n>1/2>0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Absolute value is not a monotonic function

Comment: You dont know which number has a greater distance from 0. Talking about x (or-x) and y.

Comment: As you have demonstrated, this is nonsensical. $x < y$ in no way implies $|x| < |y|$.  "Taking the absolute value" of both sides of an inequality is a misleading phrase since you are not justified in doing so without additional context. It may be helpful to mentally replace the absolute value function with an arbitrary function $f$ and consider what it would be to apply $f$ to both sides of an inequality.

Comment: So if I assumed that $x>y>0$, for example, then I would  know that $x$ is far from $0$ than $y$ and I would be able to do somthing about it? There must be more information some sort of relation between this numbers?

Comment: I'll give some context and put in the post.

Comment: If $| y|<x$ then $y<x$ and $-y<x$

Comment: In your edit, why are you even thinking about taking absolute values? I do not see what you might gain from this.

Comment: There's no reason to think comparing $x$ and $y$ will tell us anything about how $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ compare for a function.  If $x < y$ there no reason to thing that means $x^2 - 24x + 7 < y^2 - 24x + 7$ or the $\cos x < \cos y$.  So why would you think $x < y$ would mean $|x| < |y|$.

Comment: If $x,y > 0$ then $-x < 0$ so you will always have $-x < 0 < y$ no matter what $x,y$ are.  Taking the absolute values won't tell you anything and there's no reason to think it would.  For instance if $x =1$ and $y = 5,634,893$ then $-1 < 0 < 5,634,893$ and $|-1| =1 < |5,634,893|= 5,634,893.  But if $x = 8,456,912$ and $y =2$ then $-8,456,912 < 0 < 2$ but $| -8,456,912|=8,456,912> 2=|2|$.

Comment: "Given this context helps in solving my problem in taking the absolute value?"  Of course not!  You can't magically force information to appear when you have none.  I might as well try to say.  If $x > 0$ then $x > -500gazillion$ therefere $|x| > |-500gazillion|$ so $x > 500gazillion$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Apparently, you are trying to remove the absolute value from both sides from the inequality. But that's would mean you apply the inverse function to both sides, but absolute value does not have an inverse.